Firefox rendering issue for ellipses
In Firefox browser , truncation of string is not working, when typing into the input box at first time truncation is not working, but when focusing out and typing once again it start working , seems its rendering problem which is not working at first time.
Above code will give the different result in firefox and the the chrome browser.
in chrome it will work at first time , means once user will start the typing into the input box , it will start showing the ellipses once text overflow will happen.
but in Firefox it will not work like this, at first time when user will start the typing it will not show ellipses although text exceeds the boundary of input box , but when user focus out from the input box and start once again start typing into the input box ellipses will be shown. this behavior is creating confusion.
Kindly provide the solution for the same
I am using 128.5.2 esr firfox version


input.b {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

div.c {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: "----";
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
<h2>text-overflow: ellipsis:</h2> 
<input class="b" />




input.b {
white-space: nowrap;
width: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
        div.c {
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 50px;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: "----";
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>text-overflow: ellipsis:</h2>
    <input class="b" />`


You might find reading the site help section useful when it comes to asking a good question. To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a minimal reproducible example. Here's a question checklist you might find useful...

I can't really reproduce this issue on Firefox. Unlike Chrome, it does not scroll the text inside the input field to the left on blur. But the overflow behavior is the same.

This is already tracked in Bugzilla:

Like Safari/Chrome/WebKit browsers, if a text input has text-overflow:ellipsis and the value needs to be truncated, the ellipsis should appear as soon as the input element loses focus.
Steps to reproduce the problem:

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/zeBsw/
Click on the first text box and enter a value wider than the text control's width.
Either tab to the next text box or click on the "Something to Click" button.  The ellipsis does not appear until after tabbing back to the first text box.

I have tested and found the issue in Firefox 20.0 and Firefox Aurora 22.0a2 (2013-04-10).
Testing the above steps in Safari 6.0.3 and Chrome 26.0.1410.63, the ellipsis appears immediately when the first text box loses focus.


It's also discussed:

In Set input caret position on blur in Safari without refocusing input


The ellipsis isn't rendered when the end of the line of text is visible in the input:


If the end of the line of text is not visible, the ellipsis is shown as expected.


So an easy way to get the ellipsis to always show is to set the selection range scroll the input (thanks to Emilio Cobos Álvarez for pointing out that setting the selection range can have adverse effects) during the blur event to the beginning of the line. This has the effect of putting the end of the line out of the bounds of the input which causes the ellipsis to be rendered:


const input = document.querySelector('input.b');
input.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
  e.target.scrollLeft = 0;
});
input.b {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
<h2>text-overflow: ellipsis:</h2> 
<input class="b" />



